# Proper way to deal with cell reuse with background threads?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios6, nsoperation, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView`, but the same methods should apply to `UITableViews`. Each of my cells contains an image I load from disk, which is a slow operation. To mitigate this, I use an async dispatch queue. This works fine, but quickly scrolling results in these operations stacking up, such that the cell will change its image from one to another in sequence, until finally stopping at the last call.

In the past, I've done a check to see if the cell was still visible, and if not I don't continue. However, this is not working with UICollectionView, and anyway it is not efficient. I am considering migrating to use `NSOperations`, which can be cancelled, so that only the last call to modify the cell will go through. I could possibly do this by checking if the operation had finished in the `prepareForReuse` method, and cancelling it if not. I'm hoping someone has dealt with this issue in the past and can provide some tips or a solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Session 211 - Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS, from WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211), discusses the problem of the cell's image changing as the background tasks catch up (starting at 38m15s).

Here's how you solve that problem.  After you've loaded the image on the background queue, use the index path to find the current cell, if any, that's displaying the item containing that image.  If you get a cell, set the cell's image.  If you get nil, there's no cell currently displaying that item so just discard the image.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        [self bg_loadImageForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    });
    return cell;
}

- (void)bg_loadImageForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // I assume you have a method that returns the path of the image file.  That
    // method must be safe to run on the background queue.
    NSString *path = [self bg_pathOfImageForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    // Make sure the image actually loads its data now.
    [image CGImage];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self setImage:image forItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    });
}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // If cell is nil, the following line has no effect.
    cell.imageView.image = image;
}
```

Here's an easy way to reduce the "stacking up" of background tasks loading images that the view no longer needs.  Give yourself an `NSMutableSet` instance variable:

```
@implementation MyViewController {
    dispatch_queue_t myQueue;
    NSMutableSet *indexPathsNeedingImages;
}
```

When you need to load an image, put the index path of the cell in the set and dispatch a task that takes one index path out of the set and loads its image:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.image  = nil;
    [self addIndexPathToImageLoadingQueue:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)addIndexPathToImageLoadingQueue:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (!indexPathsNeedingImages) {
        indexPathsNeedingImages = [NSMutableSet set];
    }
    [indexPathsNeedingImages addObject:indexPath];
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{ [self bg_loadOneImage]; });
}
```

If a cell stops being displayed, remove the cell's index path from the set:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [indexPathsNeedingImages removeObject:indexPath];
}
```

To load an image, get an index path from the set.  We have to dispatch back to the main queue for this, to avoid a race condition on the set:

```
- (void)bg_loadOneImage {
    __block NSIndexPath *indexPath;
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        indexPath = [indexPathsNeedingImages anyObject];
        if (indexPath) {
            [indexPathsNeedingImages removeObject:indexPath];
        }
    }

    if (indexPath) {
        [self bg_loadImageForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

The `bg_loadImageForRowAtIndexPath:` method is the same as above.  But when we actually set the image in the cell, we also want to remove the cell's index path from the set:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // If cell is nil, the following line has no effect.
    cell.imageView.image = image;

    [indexPathsNeedingImages removeObject:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: Going to check out that session--not sure why I'd hadn't already. Will try your answer--thanks for being so detailed.

Comment: Getting closer with this. Almost works, but tends to load the same cell multiple times without loading the others. I think it may have to do with [indexPathsNeedingImages anyObject] returning the same index path each time.

Comment: If you're using a global queue, it's not serial.

Comment: I'm definitely using a serial queue (dispatch_queue_create(...))

Comment: I figured out the problem.  Check out the revised `bg_loadOneImage`.  It's necessary to remove the index path from the set there since `bg_loadImageForRowAtIndexPath` uses `dispatch_async` to set the image on the main thread.  Another `bg_loadOneImage` can start running on the background queue before the main queue has removed the index path from the set.

Comment: You also want to remove it in `setImage:forItemAtIndexPath:` (as I do above), because the index path might have been re-added to the set while the background task was loading its image.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for figuring that out. Excellent answer.

Comment: On the device this still causes some strange effects in single cells, but it's definitely got me in the right state of mind. Going to create a solution based on this.

Comment: I've written a post based on Apple's 211 session - http://stavash.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/advanced-issues-asynchronous-uitableviewcell-content-loading-done-right/

Comment: In `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, it should be `bg_loadImageForRowAtIndexPath` not `bg_loadImageForItemAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) open source framework that works with downloading images from the web and caching them asynchronously? It works absolutely great with `UITableViews` and should be as good with `UICollectionViews`. You just use the `setImage:withURL:` method of the `UIImageView` extension and it does magic.

Comment: +1 for SDWebImage. It's very performant in collection views and table views.

Comment: My images are sourced locally.

Comment: While SDWebImage is great, this is not a solution to the underlying problem. It's still async. Loading the images really fast from cache actually just hides the problem. If the cell is reused before the image is loaded it will load the image to the wrong cell. So the "magic" in this case is evil magic.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with an UITableView of about 400 elements and find a brutal but working solution: don't reuse cells! Depends on how much and how big the images are, but actually iOS is quite efficient in deallocating unused cells...
Again: is not what purist will suggest, but couple with async load is lighting quick, error free and don't have to deal with complex sync logic.

Comment: Even if people don't agree is a brutal but useful solution... ;)